# Trying ST_Slope with SRTM rasters and a shapefile but the output raster has different SRID

Tags: postgis, raster, coordinate-system, postgresql

I have two SRTM rasters https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM1/Region_06/ (N40W074 and N40W075) with Datum "WGS_1984"

I've united them to be able to work with one raster:

```
CREATE TABLE rasters.srtm AS
SELECT ST_Union(rast, 1) as rast
FROM (SELECT rast FROM rasters.srtm1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rast FROM rasters.srtm2) foo
```

And then used this function to create a slope for New York (this shapefile: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Borough-Boundaries/tqmj-j8zm)

```
WITH r AS ( -- union of filtered tiles
     SELECT
             ST_Transform(ST_Union(srtm.rast), 26918) AS rast
     FROM rasters.srtm as srtm
     JOIN borough_boundaries ny
             ON ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(srtm.rast::geometry, 26918), ST_Transform(ny.geom, 26918), 1000)
   ), cx AS ( -- custom extent
           SELECT
                   ST_AsRaster(ST_Transform(ny.geom, 26918), r.rast) AS rast
           FROM borough_boundaries ny
           CROSS JOIN r
   )
   SELECT
           ST_Clip(ST_Slope(r.rast, 1, cx.rast), ST_Transform(ny.geom, 26918)) AS rast
   FROM r
   CROSS JOIN cx
   CROSS JOIN borough_boundaries ny;
```

The query runs for a few minutes and produces some raster tiles, but when I try to visualize in QGIS I get the error that the raster contains different SRIDs and therefore it cannot load it. Is there a mistake in the query or a way to output raster tiles with the same SRID?

I'm using PostgreSQL 11 with PostGIS 2.5

Comment: Is you second query supposed to be a create table query? It looks OK, but could you please post the complete query.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the shapefile for New York was split in different geometries, I use ST_Union to convert them into one and the query run with an output of the same SRID.